# PowerShell Get-ChildItem and Skip

Tags: powershell, skip, get-childitem

I'm writing a PowerShell script that deletes all but the X most recent folders, excluding a folder named Data. My statement to gather the folders to delete looks like this:

```
$folders1 = Get-ChildItem $parentFolderName | 
     ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -ne "Data" } | 
     sort CreationTime -desc | 
     select -Skip $numberOfFoldersToKeep

foreach ($objItem in $folders1) {
    Write-Host $webServerLocation\$objItem
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $parentFolderName\$objItem -WhatIf
}
```

This works great when I pass a `$numberOfFoldersToKeep` that is fewer than the number of folders in the starting directory `$parentFolderName`. For example, with 5 subdirectories in my target folder, this works as expected:

```
myScript.ps1 C:\StartingFolder 3
```

But if I were to pass a high number of folders to skip, my statement seems to return the value of `$parentFolderName` itself! So this won't work:

```
myScript.ps1 C:\StartingFolder 15
```

Because the skip variable exceeds the number of items in the `Get-ChildItem` collection, the script tries to delete `C:\StartingFolder\` which was not what I expected at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not enclose your foreach in a IF statement: `if ($folder1 -neq $null) { ... } ... ` or simply use `remove-item $objectItem.fullname`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I pass `$numberOfFoldersToKeep` in with a number greater than the result of `gci` piped through the `?`, I get `$null` returned (and therefore the `foreach` doesn't even get executed), which is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: @alroc Take a look to how he removes the file ;)

Comment: @C.B. I don't even get into the `foreach` to execute `Remove-Item` because `$folders` is `$null` (when `skip` is > the item count). I see the convoluted way to get the path, but if you don't enter the loop, it doesn't matter. What am I missing?

Comment: @alroc read here: https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=281908&SiteID=99

Comment: @C.B. That explains it. I was using v3, where this bug is fixed. Hadn't tried it in v2, and AFAIK I haven't run afoul of it in my scripts that still run under v2. Now I have to go check everything I've written for the past couple years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$folders1 = Get-ChildItem $parentFolderName | 
     ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -ne "Data" } | 
     sort CreationTime -desc | 
     select -Skip $numberOfFoldersToKeep
    if ($folder1 -neq $null)

{

foreach ($objItem in $folders1) {


        Write-Host $($objItem.fullname)




 Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $objItem.fullname -WhatIf
    }
    }
```

Comment: That null test is vital! Thanks for your help. I had no idea that the body of a foreach would be executed if the collection passed to the foreach was null.

Comment: It's considere as a bug. Read my last comment to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I gave @C.B. credit for the answer, but there's another way to solve the problem, by forcing the output of Get-ChildItem to an array using the `@( ... )` syntax.

```
$folders1 = @(Get-ChildItem $parentFolderName | 
     ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -ne "Data" } | 
     sort CreationTime -desc | 
     select -Skip $numberOfFoldersToKeep)

foreach ($objItem in $folders1) {
    Write-Host $webServerLocation\$objItem
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $parentFolderName\$objItem -WhatIf
}
```

This returns an array of length zero, so the body of the foreach statement is not executed.

As C.B. noted in the comments above, the problem is that if you pass a `null` collection into a foreach statement in PowerShell, *the body of the foreach statement is executed once*.

This was completely unintuitive to me, coming from a .NET background. Apparently, it's unintuitive to lots of other folks as well, since there's bug reports filed for this behavior on MSDN: https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=281908&SiteID=99

Apparently, this bug has been fixed in PowerShell V3.